# How to parse UNC path in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, split, path

I am currently working with directories. I would like to parse the UNC path e.g.:

> //server_IP/ws1/dir2/dir3/dir4/file.xyz

and obtain names of dirs and file like that `ws1`, `dir2`, `dir3`, `dir4`, `file.xyz`? I do not want to use `std::string`. Instead, my UNC path is `char[]`. Could someone help me?

Comment: "*I do not want to use std::string. Instead, my UNC path is char[]*" What's wrong with constructing an `std::string` from `char[]`?

Comment: maybe we can help you by convincing you to use `std::string` instead of `char[]` ;) Why dont you want `std::string`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'cant use std::string' restriction sounds like a homework question, but I'll go ahead and cast some ugly code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
char unc_path[80] = "//server/ws/dir/file.abc";
char token[80] = "";
char *p = unc_path;
char *t = token;
while(*p)
{
   if(*p == '/' && *token != '\0')
   {
      *t = '\0'; /* tie off the end of string */
      fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", token);
      t = token;
      *t = '\0';
   }
   else
   {
      *t = *p;
      t++;
   }
   p++;
}
*t = '\0';
if(*token != '/0')
   fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", token);
return 0;
}
```

This is straight C, untested code.  Use at your own risk.  I'm sure it could be cleaned up a bit, but that's an exercise for the user.  This kind of does what strtok() does, feel free to look that up on cppreference.com.